# Meteor xolvio:md-blog: Site title is changed to "name"

Tags: meteor

I have finally successfully installed the Meteor package md-blog from xolvio. The only thing that is bothering me, is that the title of the site is changed to "name". Where can I remove this?

Also on some blog entries my logo in the navbar disappears. Does anyone know what this could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're basing your blog on the example app (https://github.com/xolvio/md-blog/tree/master/app), the strings used in the app are defined in the internationalization directory (https://github.com/xolvio/md-blog/tree/master/app/i18n).  You can edit the en.i18n.json file as you see fit.  The site_title property is what you need to edit to change the title of the blog.

Without seeing your blog, I can't evaluate why your logo disappears.  Inspect the page to see if it's there but not visible.  It's likely a css issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wasn't using any i18, but I set it up now. It's just a folder "i18n" with a file "en.i18n.json" with the content ```{
  "name": "mySiteTitle"
}```. This solved the problem. Thanks again! About the logo, I put "image.png" instead of "/image.png" there, so it wasn't looking at the root.